# How do I return the success value of chaining multiple Results if no errors occur or another value if any error happens?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to play with chaining multiple `Result`s. I want to write a function which receives a `&[u8]` and returns a `Tm`. If any of the steps give a error, I just want to return `time::now()`.

I wrote:

```
extern crate time;

use time::{strptime, Tm};
use std::str;

pub fn buf_to_tm(buffer: &[u8]) -> Tm {
    str::from_utf8(buffer)
        .and_then(|val| strptime(val, "%d %b %y%H:%M:%S"))
        .unwrap_or(time::now())
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:25
  |
8 |         .and_then(|val| strptime(val, "%d %b %y%H:%M:%S"))
  |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::str::Utf8Error`, found enum `time::ParseError`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, std::str::Utf8Error>`
             found type `std::result::Result<time::Tm, time::ParseError>`
  = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
          - .unwrap()
          - .unwrap_err()
```

How do I tell Rust I don't really care what type of error this code gives, I just want to return the parsed `Tm` if no errors occur or `time::now()` if any error happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just implicitly "ignore" the error type; that's just not how statically types languages work.

The straightforward change you can make is to explicitly change each potential failure to the same type using [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err). Since you don't care about the type, you can use `()`:

```
fn buf_to_tm(buffer: &[u8]) -> Tm {
    str::from_utf8(buffer)
        .map_err(|_| ())
        .and_then(|val| strptime(val, "%d %b %y%H:%M:%S").map_err(|_| ()))
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| time::now())
}
```

Even better, you can convert to an `Option` using [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) instead:

```
fn buf_to_tm(buffer: &[u8]) -> Tm {
    str::from_utf8(buffer).ok()
        .and_then(|val| strptime(val, "%d %b %y%H:%M:%S").ok())
        .unwrap_or_else(time::now)
}
```

As an additional note, you probably should use `unwrap_or_else` as I've done above. This only gets the current time in failure case; `unwrap_or` will always execute its argument. This could save some work and makes sure that the time is as "up-to-date" as it can be.

---

The "enterprise" solution would be to define a custom error type. This allows you to use `?` (the try operator):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;
extern crate time;

use time::{strptime, Tm};
use std::str;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum Error {
        Utf8(err: str::Utf8Error) {
            from()
        }
        Time(err: time::ParseError) {
            from()
        }
    }
}

fn buf_to_tm_inner(buffer: &[u8]) -> Result<Tm, Error> {
    let s = str::from_utf8(buffer)?;
    let t = strptime(s, "%d %b %y%H:%M:%S")?;
    Ok(t)
}

fn buf_to_tm(buffer: &[u8]) -> Tm {
    buf_to_tm_inner(buffer)
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| time::now())
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I've used the ok() method and everything looks nicer!

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't care about which error was the cause of the failure, you can fix this in a simple way by mapping both error types to `()`, or `Result<T, _> => Option<T>`, since `Result<T, ()>` is isomorphic to `Option<T>`.

This is done with the function [`.ok()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) seen [here](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=1b8b0e9a0ecbd9adddc2ba529f5ae8f9&version=stable):

```
extern crate time;

use time::{strptime, Tm};
use std::str;

pub fn buf_to_tm(buffer: &[u8]) -> Tm {
    str::from_utf8(buffer).ok()
        .and_then(|val| strptime(val, "%d %b %y%H:%M:%S").ok())
        .unwrap_or_else(time::now)
}
```